# A fair dice is tossed 6 times. What is the probability that there is at least one pair of identical consecutive face values?

Tags: probability, random-variables, dice

For example, 231146 is a valid sample point but 131213 is not.
This is a question on past exam that i have no idea to solve.
Please help me!

Comment: Hint: It's the converse of the probability that there are no consecutive pairs with identical face values. $P(\text{at least 1 such})=1-P(\text{none such})$

Comment: Are you making progress?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  How many throws are there for the first one that don't spoil the string?  How many throws for the second?  The third?